# Uploading images to Google App Engine using a standalone Java application

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-apps, google-cloud-datastore

I'm writing a simple, no UI (hence no .jsp/.html files), console based Java application to read image file paths from a file and upload the images to my sample photo feed application on Google App Engine.

I'm using Apache HttpClient to make the URL connection and the POST request to my app engine application and this is the code I have so far.

```
MultipartEntity multiPartEntity = new MultipartEntity();
multiPartEntity.addPart("photo", new FileBody(new File(filePath)));
multiPartEntity.addPart("title", new StringBody(comment));

HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost post = new HttpPost(uploadUrl);            
post.setEntity(multiPartEntity);

HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
```

This uploads the file and I can see it in the Blob Viewer. However, the Content-Type of the file is set to "application/octet-stream".

I want the Content-Type to be set to "image/jpeg" or "image/png" or so on depending on the image type. I tried modifying the code a bit using

```
MultipartEntity multiPartEntity = new MultipartEntity();
multiPartEntity.addPart("photo", new FileBody(new File(filePath), "image/jpeg"));
multiPartEntity.addPart("title", new StringBody(comment));
```

but this failed to even upload the file into the Blob Viewer and I still get the same response from the application servlet.

Can somebody help me crack this?